Android not showing FCM push notification while being closed/terminated
Trying to implement FCM for my Android app. When app is in background, the push notification is received and shown. When app is in foreground, my onMessageReceived is triggered. But when app is closed/terminated, not notification is shown.
I can't find any docs from Firebase regarding the closed state, but I believe it should be possible to show a push notification even if the app is not running?
Sent notification from the Firebase console, expected to see a notification in the tray even though the app was closed.

In which android version you are checking? Because latest API restricted to push notification from background either set the notification priority to high.
